# How to include binary ejb-jar(no source project) file into ear file using maven?

Tags: maven

I have an ejb-jar that is delivered by another team as a binary jar i.e. the ejb-jar contains only ejb class files(no source code). I need to include that ejb-jar as a ejb module to my ear file. My ear file has many other ejb/war modules. What is the best way to configure this thirdparty ejb-jar module into the ear using maven?

Thanks,
PB

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would simply say:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
      <modules>
        <ejbModule>
           <...>
        </ejbModule>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and don't forget to define the ejb-jar as a usual dependency to the ear project...

Answer (score 0):

To test locally, use mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your.artifact.jar -DgroupId=your.org -DartifactId=your-artifact.jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=ejb -DgeneratePom=true.

Once it is in your repository, you can use it just like any ejb dependency (as indicated by @khmarbaise).

If you are using Nexus or another artifact repository, then deploy there instead.